# Knockout: can't pass select value to function

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, knockout.js, onchange

Simple noob issue, will probably be kicking myself when I know the solution.

I'm trying to pass the value of a select into a function so I can remove that item from the array (so I can use the cut-down array for other selects - basically each value can only be chosen once), but the select is passing 'Object object' instead of the selected value.

I thought the select value was passed as the first argument by default, so I don't know what's happening. Any tips mucho appreciated.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3lliot/45ewhxph/)

html:

```
<p>Sample rate:
    <select data-bind="options: sampleRates, value: selectedSampleRate0, event: {change: addSrate}"></select>
</p>
```

js:

```
window.onload = startKnockout;

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.sampleRates = ko.observableArray([192000, 176400, 96000, 88200, 48000, 44100]);
    self.selectedSampleRate0 = ko.observable();

    self.addSrate = function (x) {
        alert(x);
    }


    return self;
}

function startKnockout() {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter of any KO `event` binding handler is the current datacontext, so in your case your `AppViewModel` and the second parameter contains the `event` object.

So you need to write:

```
self.addSrate = function (viewModel, event) {
    alert(event.target.value);
}
```

As an alternative solution you can `subscribe` on the changes of the `selectedSampleRate0` to achieve the same functionality:

```
self.selectedSampleRate0.subscribe(function (newValue){
    alert(newValue);
})
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/pgs58e5d/)

Comment: awesome thanks. I have no idea where to find any documentation that goes into this depth, the knockout website is pretty basic. presumably it assumes a lot of domain knowledge.

Comment: presumably if I use this value in a remove statement, it will take that element out of the array, so that further selects using that array will contain less values?

Comment: Maybe you looked in the wrong places in the documentation: you can find the details of the event binding here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters and the subscribe: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables. Regarding the remove: yes if you remove the item form the array it should from the dropdown : http://jsfiddle.net/ng3uw9t4/